# Spacing between heatmap point

Tags: leaflet, html5-canvas, heatmap, react-leaflet-v3

I tried to customise leaflet heatmap.js to render rectangles to generate a heatmap. I was doing good so far. But, there are spacing in between rectangles that I can't get rid of. As in the picture.
[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMwj3.png)

Solutions that I tried: turn off antialiasing, add offset. While adding offset remove the space, it creates an area with "blended color" which I don't want to have. I wonder if there is a solution to remove the gap or remove the blending color in heatmap.js.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Very unlikely to get an answer without your code

Comment: Turn out it is precision problem of the leaflet latlong to screen coordinate function. I have fixed it by recalculate the coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out it is precision problem of the leaflet latlong to screen coordinate function. I have fixed it by recalculate the coordinate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).